# How to use std::unordered_set to a vector<vector<int>> to remove duplicates

Tags: c++11

I have a std::vector<    std::vector<    int> > that contains prime numbers. I wish to eliminate double entries, as the vector contents will be exported to a file and should only contain unique primes.

The prime numbers will come from certain intervals, fed to my algorithm through a file, e.g. (32,345). There may be cases where the intervals will overlap e.g. (54,434),(345,596). I wish to use std::unordered_set, since it will be the most efficient for my case. 
I have seen examples with a     std::vector<    int> and tried to accommodate that to my needs, to no avail.

Here is code I tried, inspired by the print method of a 2d vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > sharedAnswersVec;
...
...
std::unordered_set<int> unique_primes;
for (auto i = 0; i < sharedAnswerVec.size(); i++) 
{
    for (auto j = 0; j < sharedAnswerVec[j].size(); j++) 
    {
        unique_primes.insert({ i,j });
        sharedAnswerVec.assign(unique_primes.begin(), unique_primes.end());
        sort(sharedAnswerVec.begin(), sharedAnswerVec.end());
    }
}
```

sharedAnswerVec cannot be std::vector<    int>, has to be std::vector<    std::vector<    int> >. 
With that in mind, what changes must I do in order to correct it?

I am a beginner trying to learn, so if the question seems silly to you, please bear that in mind.

Comment: "I wish to eliminate double entries" double entries of what?

Comment: `j < sharedAnswerVec[i].size()` not `j < sharedAnswerVec[j].size()`

Comment: @Caleth I have a std::vector< std::vector< int> > that contains "prime numbers". I wish to eliminate double entries of "prime numbers" from overlapping intervals.

Comment: I mean are the `std::vector<int>`s "prime numbers", or are the `int`s "prime numbers"? If it's `int`s, do you want to remove any duplicate `int`s from the 2D `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, or only from the `std::vector<int>` that they are directly contained in?

Comment: @Neil Gatenby Sadly this typo is not the problem.I get this error code 
Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: You are trying to assign a sequence of `int` to a sequence of `std::vector<int>`. There isn't a implicit conversion between those types

Comment: "`sharedAnswerVec` cannot be `std::vector< int>`, has to be `std::vector< std::vector< int> >`" Why? What does it represent in the rest of the program?

Comment: I will try to explain a bit more clearer what I want to do. The prime numbers found from each search are stored in a vector<int>. All these vectors are bunched together in a vector<vector<int>>, since they come from different threads. In two of each individual vectors the prime number 3 may have been found. When I will write the file, number 3 will be written twice, since currently I do not check if it exist in more than one vector. I found some examples performing a sort but to a 1d vector. My sharedAnswerVec is like this: sharedAnswerVec = {{2,3,5,7},{5,7,11,13}}.

Comment: So how can I make sure that when I will write the file numbers 5 and 7 will only be written once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert something into your `std::unordered_set<int>` something which is not an `int`.

It is not clear to me what your "intervals" are, or what you are doing when sorting.  Perhaps this is some use?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > sharedAnswersVec = {
        {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29},
        {2,5,11,17,23,29}
    };

    std::set<int> unique_primes;
    for ( const auto& v : sharedAnswersVec )
    {
        for ( auto i : v )
        {
            unique_primes.insert(i);
        }
    }

    for ( auto i : unique_primes )
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to adopt C++11/14 much more quickly. That did the trick. To expand on the intervals; I am reading a .xml file that has "start value" and "end value" to search for prime numbers. Nothing guarantees that there will not be an overlap e.g. (300,800) one search interval (500,900) the next. That is why I needed the sort. But since it was a 2d vector, I started thinking that I should do something similar to the iteration process. Unnecessarily complex things . Turns out it was much more simple. I really need to study more.